# What kind of bounded sentence is this?

Tags: grammar

When I was studying English, I saw such a sentence:

'One young man wrote to **us saying**, "My mother always nags me and my sister."'

What is wrong with this sentence? If there is nothing wrong, how are 'us' and 'saying' connected? By which grammatical rule?

Comment: "Us" and "saying" are not connected. The whole of the expression _saying, "My mother always nags me and my sister_" is an adjunct in which the direct reported speech _My mother always nags me and my sister_ is functioning as complement of "saying".

Comment: Why it it not ' is saying' ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not connected with "us".  You'd better understand it as being connected to "wrote".

Consider a sentence like

> He wrote to us quickly.

Now the word "quickly" is an adverb.  It is an adjunct (extra word or phrase) that describes how he wrote the letter to us.

Instead of an adverb, you could have a prepositional phrase "He wrote to us from home" or a participle "he wrote to us, eating dinner."

Or you can have a participle phrase which describes what the letter "says" (you can use "say" to describe the words that are written.) That would make the adjunct 'saying "....".  And this is the structure of the sentence:

> One young man [subject] wrote [verb] to us [complement prep phrase] saying "..." [participle adjunct].

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the sentence; it's just that you are linking the words in the wrong way.

The young man **wrote to us** (sent us a letter). In the letter he said...

This can be expressed as **he sent a letter saying...** or **he wrote saying.**

Comment: I am ok with your expressions. If it was like that two, there would be no problem. I still don't understand how this sentence structured with 'wrote us saying'

Comment: **He wrote** [sent a letter] **to us saying** [in which he said]... Does that make it any clearer?

Answer (score 0):

It would perhaps help you understand if the sentence were better punctuated.

Were I writing it I would put a comma or an em-dash after "us".

The main part of the sentence with an indicative verb is "One young man wrote to us ..."

The rest of it is an adverbial clause describing what his writing was "saying".

***One young man wrote to us - saying "My mother always nags me and my sister".***